# Can output of Spark DataFrame.saveAsCsvFile() be saved as plain text files, not .gz files?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I would like to save the contents of a Spark SQL DataFrame, `df`, as plain text file format. My DataFrame is simple, 3 integer columns:

```
1   3   10
2   5   4
3   2   34
...
```

When I use the `df.saveAsCsvFile(outputPath)` from the `com.databricks.spark.csv._` library running on a Spark cluster, the output files get saved as `part-00000.gz, part-00001.gz, ...` in HDFS.

Is there a way to save the output in plain text file format, not .gz format? Alternatively, is there a good way to `gunzip` in HDFS?

I wrote a small shell script to process the files, but this requires to copy data to local file system. This is ok for this job since part files are few KB, but would want to avoid this, if possible.

```
TEMP_DIR=spark_temp
OUTPUT=output.csv

hadoop fs -get hdfsDirName $TEMP_DIR
NUM=$(($(ls -l $TEMP_DIR | wc -l) - 2))
for i in $(seq 1 $NUM); do ls $TEMP_DIR/*.gz | head -1 | xargs gunzip ; done

rm -f $OUTPUT
cat $TEMP_DIR/part* > $OUTPUT
rm -r $TEMP_DIR
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of spark-csv do you use? You use ```saveAsCsvFile(outputPath)``` without compressionCodec? When I call ```saveAsCsvFile(outputPath)```, I get text files. If I call ```saveAsCsvFile(outputPath, compressionCodec = classOf[GzipCodec])``` I certainly get gzipped files. Can you show more code?

Comment: I should add that **locally**, everything works fine I get text files, but when I run on **cluster** I get .gz output. The entry in my build.sbt file = `"com.databricks" %% "spark-csv" % "1.0.3"` so I am using version 1.0.3 of spark-csv. I use `df.saveAsCsvFile(outputPath)` without the compressionCodec. Could the issue be resolved by a setting on the cluster?

Comment: Yes, it may be wrong with settings on the cluster. I also using spark-csv with 1.0.3 version and when I running my code on a spark cluster, I got not gzipped files. Do you save files on hdfs? Try to check ```mapred.output.compress``` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in Java. If you have a `DataFrame` then you are using spark 1.3 or greater. A data frame is just like a JavaSchemaRDD in 1.2 which basically means a JavaRDD with schema. I am sure you can use `saveAsTextFile()` function on your dataframe to save it to text file. Make sure you do a `repartition(1)` so that you just don't have multiple files. If this doesn't work the other measure would be to do a `CollectAsList` on your dataframe into a `List<Row>`.

1. Collect as list:

   ```
   List<Row> dflist = df.collectAsList();
   ```
2. And then:

   ```
   JavaRDD<Row> rddname = sc.parallelize(dflist)
   ```
3. Once you have that, save your `JavaRDD<Row>`:

   ```
   rdd.repartition(1).saveasTextFile("Path to file").
   ```